# Which tool prefer for static code analysis for WSO2 ESB Services

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have developed ESB proxy services in WSO2 EI. Now customer wants to do code verification by using some static code analysis tool. I searched online some tools like Veracode etc.. but I couldn't find suitable for verifying WSO2 services. 
Can you please suggest the recommended tool to do static code analysis for WSO2 services?

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: Did you created service using wso2 developer studio ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Some commercial users of WSO2 are known to be using [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/) for internal WSO2 code analysis. Not sure whether it can be used for analyzing services.